# MSSQL- Q1, count from a SQL result

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Hey I'm new to SQL and the the following does not work.
Basically the syntax is correct with

```
SELECT Hometeam, count(*) 
FROM [dbo].[E0$] 
GROUP BY Hometeam 
HAVING COUNT(*) >3
```

But when I count the result, it fails.

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM (SELECT Hometeam, count(*) 
FROM [dbo].[E0$] 
GROUP BY Hometeam 
HAVING COUNT(*) >3)
```

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 75
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: OT: Using CTEs instead of subqueries usually leads to nicer code.

Answer (score 1):

You need aliases for both the subquery itself and columns in it.

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM (
  SELECT Hometeam, count(*) as cnt
  FROM [dbo].[E0$] 
  GROUP BY Hometeam 
  HAVING COUNT(*) >3
) x
```

Comment: No need of the alias for the count(*) function in the subquery.

Comment: @JorgeCampos You're right, but it certainly comes handy for troubleshooting purposes.

Comment: Agree to that :)

Answer (score -1):

You have to put something in Count method.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997(v=sql.110).aspx

For example:

```
Select count(1)...
```

Comment: Count(*) is perfectly fine. the problem was addressed in the @Adam's answer.